# Changing the value of a checkbox used in a datagridview from "true" to a text value of my own choice

Tags: c#

private void attendence_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cls_Connection.connection);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select type from emp_type",conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            atten_cmb_type.Items.Add(reader["type"]);

        }
        reader.Close();

        conn.Close();

    }

    private void atten_cmb_id_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sq = new SqlConnection(cls_Connection.connection);
        sq.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter ss = new SqlDataAdapter();


        ss.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select id,Name,type from Employee_Details where type='"+atten_cmb_type.Text+"'", sq);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ss.Fill(dt);
        dgv_attendence.Visible = true;

        dgv_attendence.DataSource = dt;


        sq.Close();

    }









    string id = "";
    string name = "";
    string type = "";
    string date = "";
    string month = "";
    string attendance = "";
    string year = "";
    int a = 0;



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        id = lbl_Id.Text;
        name = lbl_Name.Text;
        type = atten_cmb_type.Text;
        date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd");
        month = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MMMM");
        year = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy");

        int j = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_attendence.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[j].Value != null)
            {
                if ((Boolean)row.Cells[j].Value == true)
                {
                    attendance = "Present";
                }
                else if ((Boolean)row.Cells[j].Value == false)
                {
                    attendance = "Absent";
                }
            }
            j++;
        }






            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cls_Connection.connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from attendence where id = '" + id+"'" + " AND date = '" + date+"'",con);

            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();    
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count < 1)
            {




                for (int i = 0; i < dgv_attendence.Rows.Count;i++)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into attendence(id,Name,type,date,month,attendence,year) values('" + dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','" + dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','" + date + "','" + month + "','" + attendance + "','" + year + "')", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }


                MessageBox.Show("success");

                con.Close();


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record already exists");
            }





    }
```

this is my code. first of all i fill gridview from 3 columns of 1 employee_details table.the same column exists in attendance table too.now when i click the button those three columns will go as it is to attendance table while the rest are taken from various controls

Comment: My last post was off the mark.  You should include more of your code.  Do you store attendance inside the datagridview?

Comment: **PLEASE!!!** Don't use `if ((Boolean)row.Cells[0].Value == true)`, it's a boolean already! use just `if ((Boolean)row.Cells[0].Value)` and `if (!(Boolean)row.Cells[0].Value)`

Answer (score 0):

You were right about using Cells[0].  the problem is you don't do anything with your results.  So you loop through all of them, and then attendance will just equal the value from the last row.

Change the loop to keep a list of all of your attendance values.  It would be better if there was a cell in the table that you updated, but this will work:

```
   List<string> listAttendance = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_attendence.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && (Boolean)row.Cells[0].Value == true )
        {
           attendance = "Present";
        }
        else
        {
            attendance = "Absent";
        }
        listAttendance.Add( attendance);
     }
```

Then your cmd is changed to use "listAttendance[i]" instead of "attendance".

```
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into attendence(id,Name,type,date,month,attendence,year) values('" + dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','" + dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','" + date + "','" + month + "','" + listAttendance[i] + "','" + year + "')", con);
```

Comment: if i check present for all the employees it works fine but if i leave checkbox unchecked it does'nt add "absent" and gives the index out of range exception at the "type" column.

Comment: Then we must have had some null values, we should make sure that we add something to the list for every item.  I have altered the code.  If it not null and it is checked use present, else use absent.

Comment: I also edited the other answer I suggested, which I like better.

Comment: thanks for the answer.i've used list view instead and it works fine.but thanks any way.will use it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can move the string logic inside the loop where you write to the database:
(and completely get rid of the other for loop where you work with "Present" and "Absent")

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_attendence.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    if ( dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null && (Boolean)dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == true)
    {
        attendance = "Present";
    }
    else
    {
        attendance = "Absent";
    }
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into attendence(id,Name,type,date,month,attendence,year) values('" + dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','" + dgv_attendence.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','" + date + "','" + month + "','" + attendance + "','" + year + "')", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        
}
```